# Typescript: Overloading event handlers

Tags: typescript, events, interface

I am trying to extend an existing interface to add additional event handlers. The interface I am extending already has several event handlers defined.

Here is the base interface:

```
export interface Emitter {

  on(event: 'connect', listener: (err: Error) => void ):this;

  on(event: 'end', listener: () => void ):this;
}
```

Here is also the base class:

```
export class Emitter extends events.EventEmitter {}
```

Here is my interface:

```
export interface EmitterExtended extends Emitter {
  on(event: 'status', listener: (status: ConnectionStatus) => void ):this;
  status?: ConnectionStatus;
}
```

And here is the error typescript gives:

```
Interface 'EmitterExtended' incorrectly extends interface 'Emitter'.
Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)

By declaring a module with the same name as the imported module, you can augment existing declarations

```
import { Observable } from "./observable";
declare module "./observable" {
    interface Observable<T> {
        map<U>(f: (x: T) => U): Observable<U>;
    }
}

Observable.prototype.map = function (f) {
    // ... another exercise for the reader
}
```